# Does "make" have implicit recipe for building shared object?

Tags: make

The implicit rules in "make" are defined on https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc-Using-Implicit-Rules. I was unable to find the default recipe for shared objects in there. Is there a default recipe when building shared objects?

I was unable to run

```
foo: foo.so
```

with error message "no rule exists"

while I could run

```
foo: foo.o
```

without explicitly adding any rule to the makefile (so there is implicit rule for building object files).

I was told by OpenAI (but could not verify it in the gnu manuals) that this is the default rule for building shared objects:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

But from what I can find, it seems to be wrong.

Comment: You linked to the manual about implicit rules. In that document, it says _To see the full list of default rules and variables available in your version of GNU make, run ‘make -p’ in a directory with no makefile._ Did you try that? If you don't see anything there re shared object creation, then there isn't a "default" one from `make` itself.

Comment: Right, good point. Did that now, can't find anything. The reason I asked is because it seemed like a common enough operation that it would have a default rule. Thanks for the comment, peace.

Answer (score 2):

In the GNU Make manual you linked, just after Chapter 10.1, *Using Implicit Rules*, there is [Chapter 10.2, *Catalogue of Built-In Rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).
As Andy Dalton notes, it says:

> To see the full list of default rules and variables available in your version of GNU make, run `make -p` in a directory with no makefile.

At least in the version of GNU make on my system, there does not seem to be any built-in rule for `*.so` targets. Although the `.LIBPATTERNS` is defined by default as `lib%.so lib%.a`, so make's default definition for shared objects would seem to be `lib*.so` rather than just `*.so`. And no, there are no default rules for that either.

Note that the basic structure of a Makefile rule is:

```
target: things_to_make_the_target_out_of ...
```

so your

```
foo: foo.so
```

would seem to be trying to make an executable out of a pre-existing shared object, which would seem to be unusual and possibly nonsense.

The OpenAI answer would seem to make sense as *the basic structure of a Makefile rule used to build shared objects*. In other words, when a Makefile is used to build a shared object, I would expect it to look something like:

```
libsomething.so: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

with at least the OBJS variable defined as appropriate.

Comment: OK thanks. With foo: foo.so, I was going for a phony target foo. I'm able to do foo: foo.so as long as I specify the rule %.so: %.c    gcc -shared $< -o $@, so I'm not sure your implication that I was by definition doing something wrong is true.

Comment: You could also just have said `make foo.so` to invoke the rule to create `*.so` files directly. Yes, I forgot that phony rules are a thing, but it seems like an unnecessary complication here. Maybe it's just a style point, but it would be more understandable to either explicitly declare `.PHONY: foo` before using a phony target, or use a target name that is commonly understood to be phony, like `all: foo.so`.

Comment: it was just an example, in the make file I work on foo target would build a few different shared objects, e.g., foo: foo1.so foo2.so foo3.so, the reason for "make file" or whatever similar is to automate things so you do not have to type out "make foo1.so foo2.so foo3.so", and the question I asked was about default rules for shared objects. thank you for your answer, peace.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such implicit rule.

But if you want, you can do:

```
# my_favorite_recipe.mk
# list of my default rules

%.so: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $(OBJ)
```

put it into some `/usr/local/include/my_favorite_recipe.mk` and in your makefile just add

```
include my_favorite_recipe.mk
```

Just do not forget to define `OBJ` list.

Comment: Right, and I guess I could add it to make directly somehow too, when I ran make -p it showed .a: for example, just like it showed a lot of other extensions, but no implicit rule was added for .a:. Thanks for the answer, peace.

Comment: @BipedalJoe And the implicit rule for `.a` is empty (at least it should be empty) because it is not obvious which object file should be included into `.a`. The implicit rule for `.so` is not possible by the same reason.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a good reason. I'll have to think about it a bit, but will probably get the limitations eventually. It is more or less that a .a file can be built from multiple source files, while a .o file is always from just a single source file? Anyway, good to know that it is not possible, I wanted to use as much default rules as I could in a makefile I am writing.